# ORA-12154 LDAP Authentication Resolving ODAC 12c r2 Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g, ldap, odp.net

I'm receiving the following Error in my MVC Web API C# project only when I try to use Oracle's OID LDAP service name resolution services for my DATA SOURCE with a database alias:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

However, when I use a local tnsnames.ora file it connects to the database.

Here is my web.config telling the project to use my LDAP service:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <LDAPsettings>
        <LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVERS" value="oid.wh.mycompany.net:3060:3061"/>
        <LDAPsetting name="DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT" value="dc=wh,dc=mycompany,dc=net"/>
        <LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE" value="OID"/>
      </LDAPsettings>
      <settings>
        <setting name="SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES" value="(NTS)"/>
        <setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH" value="(LDAP)"/>
        <setting name="SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT" value="REQUESTED"/>
        <setting name="SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT" value="(AES256,AES192,AES128,3DES168,3DES112)"/>
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EducationServiceEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.EducationServiceEntities.csdl|res://*/Entities.EducationServiceEntities.ssdl|res://*/Entities.EducationServiceEntities.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=WISEDV2;PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxx;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=EDU_PTI&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When change my NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH from (LDAP) to (LDAP,TNSNAMES), and if I create an entry in my local tnsnames.ora file for the database then I can connect to it.

I really need this to work without a tnsnames.ora file since having one would defeat the whole purpose of having an LDAP service to resolve the service name.

Thank you

Comment: Before trying this, you should make sure LDAP is working in general. Start by using SQLNET.ORA instead of a config file and put the entries in there and then use SQLPlus or ODP.NET Unmanaged driver and try to connect. You probably won't be able to, and you'll know its a more generic issue with your LDAP server rather than being specific to ODP.NET, managed driver.

Comment: The LDAP service is running.  I can use SQLPlus, TOAD, and any other tools with just the LDAP service just fine.  It's just my application that can't seem to use the LDAP service.

Comment: Yes but you mentioned having a TNSNAMES.ORA file. Have you connected with SQLPLUS after renaming all your TNSNAMES.ORA to something else to make sure LDAP is really working?

Comment: Yes, as I said before.  I can connect via sqlplus and toad using LDAP or using a local TNSNAMES.ORA.  Including, deleting all old copies of tnsnames.ora files.  I can always get it to work in SQLPLUS.